# Wamp server is orange after installing composer and laravel

Tags: laravel, wamp

I had wamp server working correctly with the icon in green and being able to code php without a problem. After installation of composer and laravel following all steps from laravel website I am not being able to run wampserver, the icon is orange. what can the problem be?

ADDITIONAL MAY 23
It was not the ports causing the problem so I uninstalled wampserver completely. Now how do I uninstall composer completely from PC so that I can retry the installations and see if they work properly.

Comment: probably you install something between you code php and install laravel that messes up the ports... example:skype....

Comment: Look at the Apache Error log and if that gives you no help look at the Windows Event Viewer for messages from Apache. You obviously did something wrong, review any changes you made to `httpd.con` or any Virtual Hosts you created

Comment: Apache not working, then check the error log. You should find it here: `C:\wamp\logs\apache_error.log`

Comment: no error mentioned in apache log, any other ideas?